# How can I update a column of a vector layer for reversed selection of features using command line?

Tags: grass-gis, select-by-location

Let it be two layers:

- one with multiple polygons,
- other with one.

The task is:

1. to select features of first layer that intersect with the second,
2. then calculate values of a new column (for example: ColC = ColB + 1) only for reversed selection (features outside of current selection).

It seems I  have to use v.select and v.edit, but I can't arrange it all together, because v.select seem to create a new layer and I want to work with the existing layer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a straightforward way to do this without creating a new layer. But you can always just overwrite the original. Here's how it could be done:
(an example using the **nc_spm_08_grass7** location)

```
# First split out the intersecting and not-intersecting features
v.select ain=lakes bin=urbanarea operator=intersect output=lakes_urban
v.select ain=lakes bin=urbanarea operator=disjoint output=lakes_not_urban
v.db.addcolumn lakes_urban col="NEW_FCODE INTEGER"
v.db.addcolumn lakes_not_urban col="NEW_FCODE INTEGER"
# Update the column only for the non-intersecting map
v.to.db map=lakes_not_urban option=query column=NEW_FCODE query_column="FCODE+1"
# And patch the two back together
v.patch -e input=lakes_urban,lakes_not_urban output=lakes_update
g.remove -f vect name=lakes_urban,lakes_not_urban
# If necessary, rename back to the original
# g.copy vect=lakes_update,lakes --overwrite
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check it when 8.3.1 version works (now I can't install addons for it)